# Conditional Rendering Doesn't Work / React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, rendering

```
const [usersOfTeam1, setUsersOfTeam1] = useState([])
const [usersOfTeam2, setUsersOfTeam2] = useState([])

socket.on("update users", ({ users, team1, team2 }) => { // receives the teams information from the server
    setUsersOfTeam1(team1)
    setUsersOfTeam2(team2)
    setUsersInTheRoom(users)
})


function Users(team) {
    if (team === 1) {
        if (usersOfTeam1.length === 0) {
            return (<Text>(Empty)</Text>)
        }
        else {
            return (<FlatList
                data={usersOfTeam1}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Text>{item.username}</Text>
                )}
            />)
        }
    }
    else if (team === 2) {
        if (usersOfTeam2.length === 0) {
            return (<Text>(Empty)</Text>)
        }
        else {
            return (<FlatList
                data={usersOfTeam2}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Text>{item.username}</Text>
                )}
            />)
        }
    }
```

I am making a small game and want to display the people in the each team before selecting teams in a room. If the user just created the room, the teams will be empty naturally. I want to make a conditional rendering according to this situation. I get the data from a socket.io connection from another component (I don't think it is very important but just saying.)

And the general return state is like this:

```
return (

    <ImageBackground source={image} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.backgroundContainer}>

        <View style={styles.teamsContainer}>

            <View style={styles.team}>
                <View style={styles.userList}>
                    <Text style={styles.teamsTexts}>TEAM 1</Text>
                    <Users team={1} />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.joinInteractive}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => {
                            socket.emit("team selected", { team: 1 })
                            navigation.navigate("Game")
                        }}>
                        <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Abel", fontSize: 30 }}>Join</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.team}>
                <View style={styles.userList}>
                    <Text style={styles.teamsTexts}>TEAM 2</Text>
                    <Users team={2} />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.joinInteractive}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => {
                            socket.emit("team selected", { team: 2 })
                            navigation.navigate("Game")
                        }}>

                        <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Abel", fontSize: 30 }}>Join</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>

        </View>
    </ImageBackground>
);
```

However, when I try to run the application, I get the following error:

**Users(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.**

Thank you.

Comment: In function Users(team){}
Add an else statement and add there return(<Text>Else statement</Text>) so we can see if the problem is in condition handling. So add:
`else {
    console.log(team);
    return(<Text>Else statement</Text>);
}`
The console log so we can see what the team is

Comment: @GandalfTheGray I did what you said and found out I didn't destructure the object at the first place. So I replaced function Users(team) with function Users({team}) and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably because you dont tell the function to return anything if team is neither 1 or 2.

```js
if (team === 1) { // First condition
        if (usersOfTeam1.length === 0) {
            return (<Text>(Empty)</Text>)
        }
        else {
            return (<FlatList
                data={usersOfTeam1}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Text>{item.username}</Text>
                )}
            />)
        }
    }
    else if (team === 2) { // Second condition
        if (usersOfTeam2.length === 0) {
            return (<Text>(Empty)</Text>)
        }
        else {
            return (<FlatList
                data={usersOfTeam2}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Text>{item.username}</Text>
                )}
            />)
        }
    // HERE --- What is the return statement if both conditions fail to meet the requirements?
```